# Will Focus Lab EE Master Config work as-is on EE3?

Tags: focus-lab-master-config, ee3, config-overrides

I have used [Focus Lab's EE Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) on every EE2 site I've built, since I heard about it. Now I am working on a site in EE3, and wondering, will this setup work as-is for EE3, or will it require any modifications? Or is there an updated version out there?

Thanks!

Comment: We have an updated version coming soon! :)

Comment: Any progress on this front, Erik?

Comment: @RickLecoat It's ready for prime time now. :) https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config/tree/EE3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! There's an EE3-ready version available on GitHub now: https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config/tree/EE3